# Changed premissions in home folders and computer won't boot

Tags: macos, startup, permission

I thought would be a good idea to run `chmod o-w,o-r,o-x` in my home folder and /var/root.

After doing that, programs were unable to start properly, saying they couldn't write to /var/folders. I moved folders to folders 2, but no joy. I ran `chmod -R 755` in both folders and things were kind of fixed, but programs couldn't access the keychain. I restored back the original /var/folders, but now all I get is the Apple loading bar stuck at boot and can't boot to safe mode. macOS Sierra, SIP disabled.

Comment: For your own good, please re-enable SIP.

Answer (score 1):

Boot to Recovery HD, choose Utilities → Terminal, run `resetpassword` and choose to reset permissions and ACLs for your user account.

If that doesn't work, you may have to reinstall macOS. SIP protects the permissions on OS files, so disabling that will allow you to run commands which break the OS.

Comment: I'm stuck at the apple logo screen, even holding Shift to go into safe mode

Comment: @Paulo Hold ⌘R on boot for recovery.